# "@ IN CNAME" in a subdomain.domain.com zone file | Requires A record, but then gives error on duplicate alias

Tags: dns, bind

The glue record provider redirects "platform.domain.com to my DNS server. Now that I have dynamic control over this domain, I'm trying to forward all requests for this domain to  to eu.loadbalancer.domain.com (a health check and server monitor) - so the user is redirected to a healthy and available server.

Because I can't resolve eu.loadbalancer.domain.com to a IP address, I have to use a CNAME (please correct me if I'm wrong on the latter statement).

My problem is that the zone file requires "@ IN A"-record to be valid, and if I add a additional record for the @-alias, the zone file becomes: invalid.

So please help me out if you got any ideas. Thanks

```
$TTL   10
@               IN SOA  @ platform.domain.com.  (
                                                        1278075871  ; serial
                                                        10          ; refresh
                                                        180         ; retry
                                                        120         ; expiry
                                                        120 )       ; minimum
@               IN NS           platform.domain.com.
@       10      IN CNAME        eu.loadbalancer.domain.com.
```

(this question probably belongs to serverfault.com)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a *very* common question.  You can't have a `CNAME` at the same point as other DNS records.  Section 3.6.2 of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034):

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no
> other data should be present; this
> ensures that the data for a canonical
> name and its aliases cannot be
> different.

Try this instead:

```
@      IN A w.x.y.z. ; IP address of an HTTP-level redirector
www    IN CNAME eu.loadbalancer.example.com.
```

in other words, use the `www` prefix for the canonical URL, and push that off to your scalable web farm.  Have the bare domain name go to a very simple web server which does nothing but HTTP redirects to the correct address.

Comment: I've done as you suggested, using a nginx http web server, redirecting based on IP. It works quick as lightning :-)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but I don't have the luxury of prepending *anything* to the domain name...